# Css bundle file is working locally but not on production (live store Bigcommerce)

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css, bigcommerce, node-sass

I'm having a problem pushing my theme live. So when I try to do that via the command stencil push everything seem to work fine with no errors on the terminal, But when I try to visit my store's live website the css file isn't loading because of a 500 error response.

I'm using tailwind CSS to add custom styles via scss file (so I'm using postCSS to compile tailwind files into a single scss file called custom.scss which then I insert on the global styles files theme.scss

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First) Try to re-save the `theme.scss` file in the live store using the live editor to see the specific error.

Second) Try to use the last version of Stencil CLI, which is 5+ with node 14, maybe you have a missing path or some incompatible code from the tailwind compilation.

Share the error from the live editor.

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with the incompatible sass directive. I have the same setup as you. Bigcommerce is using a different node-sass fork as stencil-cli, so it might work in dev but not in prod.

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/installing-stencil-cli/incompatible-directives

Error is from either one of those listed directive mismatch. The only pragmatic solution I got now is to compile it into css instead of scss: `npx tailwindcss -i ./assets/scss/tailwind-src.css -o ./assets/scss/tailwind.css --watch`

Then attach that to the base.html using:

```
{{{stylesheet '/assets/scss/tailwind.css'}}}
```